# Superuser homepage answer bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

I was just looking at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/9633/e-book-reader) that had 2 answers, but on the home page it said there were 3 answers.

**Edit:** I just went back and the third one is there now, does SU have some kind of timing problem?

Answer (score 7):

The front pages of all the sites are cached every minute, which means that recent activity takes a minute or so to show up. What this means is that someone could delete their answer so that there were only two answers in the question, but because of the timing there were still three indicated on the front page.